# Web2py subdirectories in Views Folder

Tags: web2py

a really basic question as I'm just trying to get a stronger feel for web2py:

I've created a series of placeholder controller functions in default.py along the lines of

```
def order_entry():
    return locals()
```

and as there are a lot of views I've organized by function

so for example I have

```
views/
     default/
             valuation/
                  ...
```

When I try to refer to an html file in the subdirectory `valuation` I get an error message

```
invalid function (default/valuation)
```

In the web2py book it explains that the way views and controllers work is

`application/[controller]/view` so I understand that it is looking for a controller called `default/valuation` My question is - can I use sub-directories in views? If yes, how? If not, and I need to have separate higher level folders, each with its own controller, how do I redirect (`A` Helper) from one controllers view eg `default/index.html` to another controller `valuation/value.html` for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure where you saw `application/[controller]/view`, but web2py routing results in default URLs such as `/application/controller/function` (note it is the function name within the controller that determines the URL, not the view name). You do not define routes by creating a hierarchy of views. Views are associated with particular functions, but they have no effect on the routing.

When you have a controller and function such as `mycontroller/myfunction`, if the function returns a dictionary, by default, web2py will look in the `/views/mycontroller` folder for a view file called `myfunction.html` (or `myfunction.[extension]` if the URL has an extension and the extension is anything other than "html"). You may choose a different name and/or location for the view, but in that case you have to be explicit and set the value of `response.view` prior to returning from the function.

You cannot nest controllers inside subfolders. You can have a `default.py` controller and a separate `valuation.py` controller, but not a `default/valuation.py` controller.

If you are interested in a more hierarchical URL structure, you can use URL args. When a given function is called, you can use the args to conditionally execute different logic and even use different views (which could be organized in subfolders, as you have done in your example). So, in the `default.py` controller, you could do something like:

```
def valuation():
    action = request.args(0)
    response.view = 'default/valuation/%s.html' % action
    if action == 'order_entry':
        ...
        return dict()
    elif action == 'show_orders':
        ...
        return dict()
```

Then you would have URLs like `/default/valuation/order_entry` and `/default/valuation/show_orders`.

You might find it helpful to read the documentation on [dispatching](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/04/the-core#Dispatching).

Comment: thanks @Anthony - decided it was more efficient to work with the system and have just flattened each folder up with views as parent - it all works very well.